# How to plot bar graph with two column values parallely in a single figure using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a pandas dataframe which shows in each shopping mall, how much the males spend money and how much the females spend money. Its like this -

```
   ShoppingMall   MaleSpends   FemaleSpends
0     XX             5600.20        4500.70
1     YY             9000.00        100000.00
2     zz             7809.45          5600.89
```

In one graph I have to plot the malespends and femalespends.

I can plot the graphs separately in plotly -

```
import plotly.express as px
fig1=px.bar(data,x='ShoppingMall',y='MaleSpends',barmode='group')
fig2=px.bar(data,x='ShoppingMall',y='FemaleSpends',barmode='group')
```

But I need to plot the money spent by males and females in one figure.
A screenshot is shown .[image]

Comment: Can you try; `data.set_index('ShoppingMall', inplace=True)
    data.plot()`?

Comment: That is generating a line graph. I need to create a bar graph like the one shown in image and I need to do that using plotly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, using plotly's expres function to create the code, the graph can be created with the following one line.

```
px.bar(df, x='ShoppingMall', y=['MaleSpends', 'FemaleSpends'], barmode='group')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create a figure with two traces
fig = go.Figure()

# First trace for MaleSpends
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=data['ShoppingMall'],
        y=data['MaleSpends'],
        name='Male Spends'
    )
)

# Second trace for FemaleSpends
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=data['ShoppingMall'],
        y=data['FemaleSpends'],
        name='Female Spends'
    )
)

# Update layout to show the legend and to stack the bars
fig.update_layout(
    barmode='group',
    title_text='Spending by Gender in Shopping Malls',
    xaxis_title='Shopping Mall',
    yaxis_title='Spends',
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

This will create a grouped bar plot where each mall has two bars side-by-side - one for `MaleSpends` and another for `FemaleSpends`. If you want a stacked bar plot where each mall has a single bar, with `MaleSpends` and `FemaleSpends` stacked on top of each other, just change `barmode` to `'stack'` in the `update_layout` call.